# Taking a snapshot of a UIWebView is missing UIWebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uikit

I've successfully managed to take snapshots of an htmls array I have stored locally. The problem is that if the html is small with only a string of text there's a good chance the process of `webViewDidFinishLoad` will be too fast and will load the next html without taking a snapshot of it. How can I make sure that every html is snapshoted before moving on to the next html?

```
[_tempWebView loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil]; //starting the process of the `webViewDidFinishLoad` loop
```

...

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
        [self captureScreen:webView];
}

-(void)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [_snapshot addObject:viewImage];
}
```

Comment: Are you experiencing this bug or only assume it's possibility? This code does not have async tasks before loadHTMLString:baseURL: and all this performs in one main thread, so I think that every html will be captured.

Comment: I'm experiencing it. I have 15 htmls, most of them are with pictures , divs etc but between of them there are 6 htmls that every one of them is written like so:11111111111111111 , 2222222222222222 , 33333333333333, (a test I made) At the end of the process I'll get 15 snapshots but with duplicates such as 2 pictures of 111111111, 2 pictures of 444444444 while 2222222222 and 333333333 will be missing.

Comment: what if executing captureScreen: via [self performSelector:@selector(captureScreen:) withObject:view afterDelay:0.0]?

Comment: What you describe sounds close to impossible when looking at your code. Make sure your html array contains all the stuff you think it would.

Comment: @PaulNadolinskyi The big htmls will ne snapped fine but I'll get 6 snapshots of 11111. First time I got better results so there's defiantly something delay related. Till ~ I'm sure of the content of the array. At first I thought that maybe the cache of the UIWebView doesn't have enough time to clear before the next html load + snapshot but clearing it before the next load didn't changed anything.

Comment: btw, if i'll increase the delay time to 5 for example like this: `[self performSelector:@selector(captureScreen:) withObject:webView afterDelay:5.0];` I will only get one snapshot for some reason.

Comment: Well, yes, of course if you delay the CaptureScreen: call then the webview is going to cycle through all the loads before the capture call ever happens. So that makes sense.

Comment: Try putting that delay before the next load call (you may have to break the "load next" line out into a separate method). This will allow you to see if there's a rendering delay where the webview has finished loading, but UIKit hasn't yet finished drawing the new content on the screen (they're not the same "finished").